# Unbound Module (Personal Files)

Tags: ocaml

I have two `.ml` files, `type.ml` and `main.ml`, in the same directory.

I am following this official link: https://ocaml.org/docs/modules

File `main.ml`:

```ml
open Type

let () = print_endline "Hello World!"
```

I compile with this line, accordingly to the tutorial:

```bash
ocamlopt -o main main.ml type.ml
```

However, I have this error:

```
Error: Unbound module Type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source files need to be ordered with the dependencies coming before the dependent. That is, it should be:

```bash
ocamlopt -o main type.ml main.ml
```

This is somewhat vaguely explained in [the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/native.html#s:native-overview):

> The order in which .cmx and .ml arguments are presented on the command line is relevant: compilation units are initialized in that order at run-time, and it is a link-time error to use a component of a unit before having initialized it. Hence, a given x.cmx file must come before all .cmx files that refer to the unit x.

Also, if you're doing anything more significant I would recommend using a build system like [dune](https://dune.build/) to avoid having to mess with details like this.

Comment: Thank you. This should 100% be in the link I mentioned.

Comment: I agree, so I created a PR to fix it: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml.org/pull/557 If you encounter any other issues with the documentation there's a "Contribute" button on the bottom of each page that will take you straight to the source on GitHub.

Comment: Ah, apparently you figured that out on your own :) I'll close mine then!